# The relation between two characteristic subgroups in finite p-group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite $p$-group. Let
\begin{align*}
\mho_{1}(G)=\langle a^p\mid a\in G\rangle,\quad\Omega_{1}(G)=\langle a\in G\mid a^p=1\rangle.
\end{align*}
There are examples such that $|G|\leq |\mho_{1}(G)||\Omega_{1}(G)|$ and   $|G|\geq  
 |\mho_{1}(G)||\Omega_{1}(G)|$. For $G=Q_{8}$, we computed $|\mho_{1}(G)||\Omega_{1}(G)|=4$. It's easy to construct  $p$-groups of nilpotency class $p$ satisfy $|\mho_{1}(G)||\Omega_{1}(G)|$ strict less than $|G|$ for any odd prime number.

For $G$ be an arbitrary regular $p$-group, from P. Hall's known paper in 1932, we know $|G|= |\mho_{1}(G)||\Omega_{1}(G)|$.

We can get some $p$-groups satisfy $|G|$ strict less than $|\mho_{1}(G)||\Omega_{1}(G)|$ from $p$-central group. My question is that whether $|\mho_{1}(G)||\Omega_{1}(G)|$ is characterized by $|G|$ in general. I hope get lower bound and upper bound of $|\mho_{1}(G)||\Omega_{1}(G)|$ from $|G|$.

Comment: The formulation of the question is a bit confusing. Call it $f(G)$. Clearly, as you explained, $f(G)$ is **not** characterized by $|G|$. You indeed mentioned that $f(G)=|G|$ in the regular case and that there are cases with $|f(G)|<|G|$. You didn't say whether $|f(G)|>|G|$ can occur. The question seems to be "What are good lower bounds and upper bounds for $f(G)$. Of course $1\le f(G)\le |G|^2$ and this is far from optimal.

Comment: In fact, the example that $|f(G)|>|G|$ can be found in $semi-p-abelian$ group. In the groups,$|G/\Omega_{1}(G)|=|\mho_\{1\}(G)|$ and not every groups satisfy $\mho_\{1\}(G)$ is a group. Then exist some $semi-p-abelian$ groups satisfy $|G|<|f(G)|$.

Comment: Please don't write text in math mode. You can use * signs to write italics.

Comment: Thanks,i will be careful it.